# Removing items from a list in Blazor view returning "cannot convert "void to object" error

Tags: c#, html, .net, list, blazor

Writing a Blazor app and running into an error with trying to clear items from a list. Essentially I want a table which shows their name and each of their individual dietary requirements

Here is my code section on the Blazor page:

```
private List<User>? Users = new List<User>();
private List<string>? dietaryRequirementsIndividual = new List<string>();
private string? reqs;

Users = await teams.GetUsers(teamName);
```

This returns a list of Users who have two different fields - Name and Dietary Requirements. Dietary Requirements can have many different requirements inside of it. The User model is basic:

```
public class User()
{
    public string Name;
    public List<DietaryRequirements> dietaryRequirements;
}
```

And then Dietary Requirements model is:

```
public class DietaryRequirement()
{
    public string requirement;
}
```

**Constructors removed for brevity**

In my Blazor HTML I am accessing the List of Users as follows:

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var user in Users)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@user.Name</td>

            @foreach(var req in user.DietaryRequirements)
            {
                dietaryRequirementsIndividual.Add(req.Requirement);
            }

            @reqs = @String.Join(",", dietaryRequirementsIndividual);
            
            <td>@reqs</td>

            @dietaryRequirementsIndividual.Clear();
            
        </tr>
```

Essentially I want a table which shows their name and each of their individual dietary requirements. I did have it as follows previously:

```
<td>@user.Name</td>
@foreach(var dietaryRequirement in user.DietaryRequirements)
{
    <td>@dietaryRequirement.Requirement</td>
}
```

The issue with this was it was creating a new cell in the table for each requirement so the row could be really long.

I have changed it to the HTML in the fourth block which is now only making one cell with a nicely formatted string. However, the issue is the list is never being cleared so the items stay in there and are never being removed. So if person one is Halal and person two is Kosher, person two will have Halal and Kosher displayed as the list hasn't been cleared. Normaly I would simply call clear on the list `dietaryRequirementsIndividual` as the last part of the code block in the loop. However, when I add this at the bottom of the loop as shown, I get an error `Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'object'`.

I am not sure how else to clear the list without calling clear and I'm not sure why this error is being thrown either. Can someone let me know how to fix this or if there's a better way to go about it?

Answer (score 0):

You could make a tweak to the model `User` to do the following:

```
public class User()
{
    public string Name;
    public List<DietaryRequirements> dietaryRequirements;
    
    public string RequirementsToString() {
         return string.Join(",", dietaryRequirements);
    }
}
```

Makes it so that you can just do this in the Blazor:

```
@foreach (var user in Users)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@user.Name</td>
        <td>@(user.RequirementsToString())</td>
    </tr>
}
```

There's no point in doing a nested for loop if you don't need to.

Comment: The backend lives on Azure functions, how would I access this from the FE side?

Comment: How do you mean? You'd access the User model the same as you already do.